Titulo con bordes en Java me sale descuadrado
estoy aprendiendo Java y tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el que muestre un título rodeado por bordes hechos con Unicode, pero el borde se detiene a la mitad del texto y no sé donde tengo el fallo ,alguien me podría decir dónde está mi error? Mil gracias.
public class EjercicioBordes {
// En mayusculas porque son constantes
static final char LINEA_VERTICAL = '║';
static final char LINEA_HORIZONTAL = '═';
static final char ESQUINA_SUP_IZQ = '╔';
static final char ESQUINA_SUP_DER = '╗';
static final char ESQUINA_INF_DER = '╝';
static final char SEPARADOR_SUP = '╦';
static final char SEPARADOR_INF = '╩';
static final char SEPARADOR_IZQ = '╠';
static final char SEPARADOR_DER = '╣';
static final char SEPARADOR_CRUZ = '╬';
static final char SEPARADOR_FILAS_MATRICES = '■';
static final int BORDE_SUP = 0;
static final int BORDE_INF = 1;
static final char ESQUINA_INF_IZQ = '╚';

public static void main(String[] args) {

    mostrarTitulo("Hoy es Viernes");

}

static void mostrarTitulo(String titulo) {

    titulo = titulo.toUpperCase();

    // BORDE SUPERIOR
    System.out.print(ESQUINA_SUP_IZQ);
    for (int i = 0; i < titulo.length() * 2 + 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(LINEA_HORIZONTAL);

    }
    System.out.println(ESQUINA_SUP_DER);

    // TEXTO
    System.out.print(LINEA_VERTICAL + "  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < titulo.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(titulo.charAt(i) + "  ");

    }
    System.out.println(" " + LINEA_VERTICAL);

    // BORDE INFERIOR

    System.out.print(ESQUINA_INF_IZQ);
    for (int i = 0; i < titulo.length() * 2 + 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(LINEA_HORIZONTAL);

    }
    System.out.println(ESQUINA_INF_DER);

}

}
Aquí lo que me sale por terminal:
╔═══════════════════════════════╗
║  H  O  Y     E  S     V  I  E  R  N  E  S   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╝

Hola Pablo!, tenése dos errores, en tres lugares, dos veces aparece for( int i = 0; i < titulo.length() * 2 + 3; i ++ ) { que debería ser for( int i = 0; i < titulo.length() * 3 + 2; i ++ ) {, después aparece System.out.println( " " + LINEA_VERTICAL ); que debería ser System.out.println( LINEA_VERTICAL );

el ancho del borde no coincide con la cantidad de caracteres impresos en la línea de texto porque estas añadiendo espacios en cada caracter del titulo al principio y al final del texto despues de cada letra y hace que todo no coincida, ajusta el tamaño del borde inferior y superior con los caracteres del titulo: titulo.length() + 4 par aincluir espacios adicionales en cada lado.. y a ver nos dices como te fue o a ver que podemos ajustar si no da!..
public class EjercicioBordes {

static final char LINEA_VERTICAL = '║';
static final char LINEA_HORIZONTAL = '═';
static final char ESQUINA_SUP_IZQ = '╔';
static final char ESQUINA_SUP_DER = '╗';
static final char ESQUINA_INF_DER = '╝';
static final char ESQUINA_INF_IZQ = '╚';

public static void main(String[] args) {
mostrarTitulo("Hoy es Viernes");
}

static void mostrarTitulo(String titulo) {
titulo = titulo.toUpperCase();

int anchoTitulo = titulo.length() + 4; // 2 espacios a cada lado

System.out.print(ESQUINA_SUP_IZQ);
for (int i = 0; i < anchoTitulo; i++) {
    System.out.print(LINEA_HORIZONTAL);
}
System.out.println(ESQUINA_SUP_DER);

System.out.print(LINEA_VERTICAL + "  "); // 2 espacios antes del titulo
System.out.print(titulo);
System.out.println("  " + LINEA_VERTICAL); // y 2 espacios despues

 System.out.print(ESQUINA_INF_IZQ);
for (int i = 0; i < anchoTitulo; i++) {
    System.out.print(LINEA_HORIZONTAL);
}
System.out.println(ESQUINA_INF_DER);
}
}

